# Why is this jquery code not working on page load? (Wordpress template)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hi");
    $('body #pagetop').css("height", "38px");
});
```

I checked that jquery is loading properly, so there is something wrong with my jquery code. Neither the "hi" will pop up or the css of the #pagetop element change. I want this code to load when the page first loads up.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: TypeError: $ is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$(document).ready(function() {i just checked console in firebug and it had this

Comment: Because you are A) not loading jQuery properly, B) including this file BEFORE you include jQuery.

Comment: I tried this code to test that jquery is loading properly http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-jquery-library-is-loaded/   and my jquery code is appearing after the jquery library in the html code

Comment: C) using something else that is overwriting the dollarsign.

Comment: I recommend you use `$(document).on('ready', function(){...});`, not that this will change the functionality.

Comment: Post the complete code from your test page please.

Comment: how would I be able to check if something is overwriting the dollarsign?

Comment: @SableFoste - That was [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in 1.8, so I suggest you don't !

Comment: @adeneo, I didn't know that, and checking the documentation, I don't see any indication.  Can you point to the deprecation link?

Comment: Sure, it's in my comment above? click the word "deprecated", and scroll down and read !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    alert("hi");
    $('body #pagetop').css("height", "38px");
});
```

Here's a guide to using jQuery with other libraries: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

I also recommend using this code (from the HTML5 Boilerplate):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

This will ensure that a copy of jQuery is loaded even if the CND is down. Just replace `path/to/` with the to a local copy of jQuery.

Note: if you're running this locally add `http:`  to the Google CDN src.

Comment: that worked. So I guess the dollar sign becomes a conflict due to something in the template code of the wordpress template I'm using. Is there a way to know if this is the case so I can test for it in the future?

Comment: Oh God, you're using wordpress !!! jQuery is in no-conflict mode by default in Wordpress, and the dollarsign does'nt work in wordpress. How about adding the wordpress tag to the question, and reading the codex -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers !

Answer (score 1):

There is probably $ sign overriden by some other library you're using.
To ensure $ belongs to jQuery use immediate-function:

```
(function($) {
    //...
})(jQuery);
```

Remember also about the method: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) if you're using conflicting JS libraries:

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(function() {
    alert("hi");
    jq('body #pagetop').css("height", "38px");
});
```

Or with combination with previous:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        alert("hi");
        $('body #pagetop').css("height", "38px");
    });
})(jQuery.noConflict());
```